# Creating a readonly textfield without the field in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, text

Essentially what I'm looking for a is an `xtype: 'text'` but with the `fieldLabel` property on it. I know I can use `textfield` but I want my text to be `readOnly: true` and the field and the cursor should not exist.

I know I could just do `xtype: 'text'` and have its text value like: `text: 'Label: My Text'` but then I lose the ability to use the `setText(value)` method in order change just the text AFTER the label. Using `xtype: 'text'` forces be to create workarounds in order to keep the label intact and I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't [displayfield](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Display) the field you are looking for?

Comment: wasn't aware of the existence of this field, nice

Comment: Same here. I knew it existed somewhere but I was searching the docs for anything with "text" in it and missed that -_-. I had to create a custom one that is now useless. Oh well